# I need to create trigger using api

Tags: trigger, api, create

Hi I need help how I can start creating trigger using api.

Here's the pay load

```js
{
    "membershipAccount": {
        "cs_email": "bran.phdev+86@gmail.com",
        "cs_code": "10000000522300",
        "cs_expdate": "2024-06-30",
        "cs_name": "mar javier",
        "cs_fname": "Bran",
        "cs_mname": "M",
        "cs_lname": "Orph",
        "cs_autocreate_acc": 1
    }
}
```

How I can add the end point as well the payload so whenever the customer signed up, we will send the customer details to different system through api

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. "Create a trigger using the API" is a phrase that has a _very specific meaning_, (literally, creating an Apex trigger on some SObject, using the Metadata API to do so) and I get the feeling that that isn't what you're talking about here. Since we can't read your mind or log into your org, it's important that you give us _plenty of details_ about what you're trying to do. You should focus on what your overall problem is (creating a trigger is a solution that you've chosen, not the problem). Please [edit] your question to add details.

Comment: Also, be aware that there is a big difference between the Marketing Cloud, and the rest of Salesforce's "Clouds" (Sales, Service, Commerce, etc...). If you're using Marketing Cloud, you should specifically call that out by adding the relevant tag to your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can create a callout by doing something like this :
[Apex Callout, how to set body?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241726/apex-callout-how-to-set-body)

and to call from trigger you can use the below example:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005mnCQAQ

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, and I believe that the official Salesforce dev forum is not a source of high-quality information (>= 95% of the worthwhile answers seem to just be links back here to SFSE). I don't think there's sufficient information in the question at this time for any of us to give a good answer.

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://staging.landers.ph/rest/V1/membership');
request.setMethod('POST');

{
"membershipAccount": {
"cs_email": "bran.phdev+86@gmail.com",
"cs_code": "10000000522300",
"cs_expdate": "2024-06-30",
"cs_name" : "mar javier",
"cs_fname": "Bran",
"cs_mname": "M",
"cs_lname": "Orph",
"cs_autocreate_acc": 1
}

request.setBody(body);
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);